# How do I view an exception log for Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I would like to view all exceptions thrown in the last 72 hours in my production Azure SQL Database.  A SQL query would be ideal, but I'll settle for any method, such as navigating to a web page in the Azure Portal.

I want the log to include any and all SQL statements (and ideally stored procedure / function calls) that threw exceptions.  Example exceptions would be integrity constraint violations, deadlocks, etc.

Ideally, the returned columns would be the timestamp, error message and the offending statement/call.

The only thing I've found so far is sys.event_log, but unfortunately that only contains connection and deadlock logging information, and not general exceptions.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: check out this  link on how to add event target as azure storage :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-xevent-code-event-file

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try extended events:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION azure_monitor
ON DATABASE

ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported(
ACTION (sqlserver.client_app_name, sqlserver.client_hostname, sqlserver.session_id, sqlserver.sql_text,
        sqlserver.username))

ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
(SET max_memory = 500, max_events_limit = 10 )
;

ALTER EVENT SESSION azure_monitor
ON DATABASE
STATE = START;

-- Some errors occurred

-- Query captured errors

SELECT CAST(target_data AS XML)
FROM sys.dm_xe_database_sessions AS s
JOIN sys.dm_xe_database_session_targets AS t
ON t.event_session_address = s.address
WHERE s.name = N'azure_monitor';

-- Stopping

ALTER EVENT SESSION azure_monitor
ON DATABASE
STATE = stop;

ALTER EVENT SESSION  azure_monitor
ON DATABASE
DROP TARGET package0.ring_buffer;

DROP EVENT SESSION azure_monitor
ON DATABASE;
GO
```

Comment: FYI:since the user requires 72 hours of data,i believe ring buffer would be overridden..so the target should be blob storage  `ADD TARGET
        package0.event_file
            (
            -- TODO: Assign AzureStorageAccount name, and the associated Container name.
            -- Also, tweak the .xel file name at end, if you like.
            SET filename =
                'https://gmstorageaccountxevent.blob.core.windows.net/gmcontainerxevent/anyfilenamexel242b.xel'
            )
    WITH
        (MAX_MEMORY = 10 MB,
        MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 3 SECONDS)
    ;`